# c++ design pattern

Tags: c++, oop

is this ok? im basically replacing a call to a single function referencing globals, by a class encapsulating all game entities and logic, the following is how i would like to call the new class in main, was just wondering what is the general c++ guru consensus on this.

```
class thingy
{
public:
    thingy()
    {
        loop();
    }
    void loop()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            //do stuff

            //if (something)
                //break out
        }
    }
};

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{
    thingy();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uh, why not just have `loop` be its own function?

Comment: Instead of having main do everything under the sun you made a class which encapsulates another function which does everything under the sun called from the constructor? I wouldn't call this a design pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not common to have a constructor that contains the game/events/... loop, the usual way to do stuff like that is to use the constructor to set up the object, and then provide a separate method that starts the lengthy elaboration.

Something like this:

```
class thingy
{
public:
    thingy()
    {
        // setup the class in a coherent state
    }

    void loop()
    {
        // ...
    }
};

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{
    thingy theThingy;
    // the main has the opportunity to do something else
    // between the instantiation and the loop
    ...
    theThingy.loop();
    return 0;
}
```

Actually, almost any GUI framework provides an "application" object that behaves just like that; taking e.g. the Qt framework:

```
int main(...)
{
    QApplication app(...);
    // ... perform other initialization tasks ...
    return app.exec(); // starts the event loop, typically returns only at the end of the execution
}
```

Comment: so would it be best for the loop() not to be called in the constructor, and just create an instance of class thingy, then call loop on that object?

Comment: Looks like I'm too slow again!

Comment: Another reason to not make the main loop in constructor is, that handling resource management while catching exceptions may be tricky in constructor.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a C++ guru, but I would probably do it like this instead:

```
struct thingy
{
    thingy()
    {
        // set up resources etc
    }

    ~thingy()
    {
        // free up resources
    }

    void loop()
    {
        // do the work here
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    thingy thing;
    thing.loop();
    return 0;
}
```

The constructor is for constructing the object, not for handling your entire application's logic. Likewise, any resources you acquire in your constructor should be handled appropriately in the destructor if need be.